# index.jsp in war file under Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to run simple web app on my local tomcat - the app is basically what you get when you crate "web application" in IntelliJ, so the directory structure is "vanilla". I am literally not touching either index.jsp or web.xml.

I am doing this under Maven, so here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_App_1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

So here is what I am doing:

1. Building this "project" under maven: `mvn compile install`
2. I am copying app_name.war file from my local repo into tomcat webapps directory
3. Running tomcat: `catalina start`
4. I can see that my application IS THERE in manager, but when I try to enter it (or when I just type http://localhost:8080/app_name) the 404 error occurs.

What I am doing wrong? Am I not understanding some basic concept or missing some basic thing? Should I somehow explicitly INCLUDE this index.jsp into my .war file somehow? If so, how do I do that under IntelliJ? I am literally just trying to run this "vanilla" application and I am under the impression, that index.jsp should be a part of this .war file and it should be displayed "automatically". And when I do it manually, so I will just create some TestDirectory in webapps folder, copy the same index.jsp file and place it in that directory, and then acces it http://localhost:8080/TestDirectory - it automatically displays this index.jsp file as it should.

Sorry for, probably, dumb question, I am really new to this and I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: *I am under the impression, that index.jsp should be a part of this .war file*: why don't you check?

Comment: Well does the .war file contain index.jsp? A war file is just a zip file, you can at least see if it's missing from the war (although probably not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove maven-war-plugin ,after that  build and redeploy and test in server

Comment: Thanks for you answer - it was partially helpfull. As you can see I had included war plugin conf to provide the path to web.xml, because maven couldn't find it on its own. It turns out that IntelliJ creates web directory (which contains WEB-INF/web.xml and index.jsp) in the root directory of the project, while it should be placed in the ...\src\main and the name of the directory should be 'webapp'. So after changing the project structure (and removing war plugin, because it is irrelevant at this point) everything works just fine. Thank you.